# Run dotnet 1.1 using docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, .net-core

I'm trying to run an .NET Core app on my mac. I'm using VS Core and upgraded the project to .NET 1.1. Everything works fine when I run it through VSCode however when I get to run it using Docker it fails.

I do the following steps:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o out
docker build -t myApp .
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.1.0-preview1-runtime
WORKDIR /service
COPY out ./service/
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myApp.dll"]
```

Essentially I'm following the steps from https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker . I'm getting all the time the following error:

> Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK
>   from:    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409

I'm not sure what I am missing here...

Comment: Is your application called *myApp*?

Comment: I found what happened. My WORKDIR was /service however I was copying everything to ./service/ so when I ran myApp.dll wasn't finding it. A bit of a wrong error message in my opinion. I changed the dockerfile to do: COPY out ./ and everything worked

Comment: `dotnet` was probably not seeing the dll you were specifying and assuming you were trying to run one of the SDK commands.

Comment: Yes, that's what I think - thanks!

Comment: at the moment, it's also 100% strict on having only "dll" after the first dot in your entrypoint assembly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I changed my dockerfile to have the following COPY statement:

```
COPY out ./
```

That then made the entrypoint to work because it was then able to find out myApp.dll. I think the message could be improved here, but that's me assuming that's what happened

Comment: This opaque error could also come from DLL-name over-opinionation (see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812386/dockerize-an-asnet-core-webapi/48812472#48812472)