# Simple(st) Dockerfile for Dotnet Core Aspnet 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

Why does my Dockerfile in OSX below get stuck on `dotnet restore` and does not make it to `dotnet run`?
(it works when I execute the commands manually)

```
Step 8 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in 3ef8b4c1d107
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
VOLUME /Documents/Docker/dnc
EXPOSE 80
ENV "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80"
RUN mkdir app
RUN cd app
RUN dotnet new -t web
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40475438/run-dotnet-1-1-using-docker?rq=1) I found out I was missing a `WORKDIR`.
The correct code is:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet
VOLUME /Documents/Docker/dnc
EXPOSE 80
ENV "ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80"
RUN mkdir app
# RUN cd app <- turned out was not necessary.
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet new -t web
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet run
```