# Dockerize an asnet core webapi

Tags: docker, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm trying to dockerize a aspnetcore webapi. I followed the tutorial here:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

But when I run my container I have this message:

```
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

I download the code and build the image from the Dockerfile the github site:

```
https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker-samples/tree/master/aspnetapp
```

I run the container... and it works... I compared two Dockerfile and they are very similar:

Mine:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0.5-2.1.4 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.5
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "fnizz.webapi.dll"]
```

And the one from the github sample:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

If there is missing info, tell me, I'll add it. Thank you !

Comment: i believe youd get that error if it didn't see your dll in there; and ive had other weirdness with dll names, e.g it might see `.webapi.dll` as the extension

Comment: Thank you I try... we never know ;)

Comment: my answer pitch would be an easier experiment than proj rename

Comment: Ok, I will try your answer... it was just to test and it was that !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping a `RUN ln -s fnizz.webapi.dll entrypoint.dll` and changing your ENTRYPOINT to `ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "entrypoint.dll" ]`. I believe `dotnet` might be finnicky on DLL extensions. This pattern also lets you genericize the assembly name -- sometimes useful.